# How to determine if 2d array contains a contiguous box?

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

I'm trying recreate a game in python, and I need to be able to determine if a given matrix contains  a contiguous box and then return which elements are enclosed by that box. In this case, the matrix is the board and and each element is a game piece.

For example, the matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

contains a contiguous box, and the element inside that block in this case is (4,3). We also assume that there is a hypothetical wall of ones on the outside of the array such that:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

forms a contiguous box, with the elements (0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8) being boxed in. The key is that it MUST be contiguous on all sides, so the matrix

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

would return nothing. (Additionally, diagonals do not apply here, only elements next to each other to the left, right, up or down.)

I've tried a few things to implement this such as a recursive solution similar to the flood fill algorithm, but I was unable to get it to apply to all cases. Any suggestions to solving this problem?

Comment: What's the smallest possible box? Is it guaranteed there will only be one box? What is the minimum number of sides a box can have (would a vertical/horizontal line of ones count as a box, which side is trapped if so)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @0x263A It is not guaranteed there will only be one box. I suppose the smallest possible box would be one in the corners with three 1s. It is a good question about the vertical/horizontal line as I don' think the rules give an answer to this. Although with the mechanics of the game it would make it near impossible for this situation to arise.

Comment: "I've tried a few things to implement this such as a recursive solution similar to the flood fill algorithm, but I was unable to get it to apply to all cases."--please share your attempts. Is it guaranteed that the box will have zeroes inside it? What if two boxes are adjacent, do we threat them as two separate results, return the first or return the larger box? I don't feel like the spec is clear enough here.